# Having Trouble Setting Window's Owner in Parent's Constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, window

Is there anything wrong in WPF with setting the Owner property of a window to its parent in that parent's constructor? There shouldn't be, right? So why am I getting an `XamlParseException` from the following code?

```
public partial class MainView : Window
{
    private readonly OwnedWindow owned;

    public MainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        owned = new OwnedWindow();

        owned.DataContext = DataContext;

        var window = GetWindow(this);
        owned.Owner = this;  //Setting to window causes the same error

        ...
    }
```

I should clarify that removing the `owned.Owner = this;` also removes the runtime error.

The details of the exception:

**XamlParseException was unhandled**

> The invocation of the constructor on type '...MainView' that matches
>   the specified binding constraints threw an exception.

*Actually*, I looked at the Inner Exception, and it says:

> Cannot set Owner property to a Window that has not been shown
>   previously.

So I'm looking into that now.

Comment: Can you post the details of the XamlParseException?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that because WPF only creates the native window the first time a WPF Window is shown, you can't be setting a not-yet-shown Window as an `Owner` (since that establishes a native window "owner -> owned" relationship, but the native handle doesn't yet exist.)

You can handle the `StateChanged` event on the owner window, ensure that the new state is "shown", and then set the owned window's `Owner` at that point. Alternatively, you could *create and show* the owned window at that point.

Comment: Okay, so how do I make sure that `OnStateChanged` is called (e.g. "that the new state is 'shown'")?

Comment: `StateChanged` is an event, so you can subscribe to the event in your constructor, and then unsubscribe in the handler (since you only need to set the `Owner` property once.)

Comment: Ah good idea for the unsubscribe. But what I'm saying is, my window's state isn't changing after the constructor like I need it to be. The method is only being called on Minimize or Maximize.

Comment: @Joseph Ah, I see. In that case, you may just want to call `Show()` on the main window in the constructor.

Comment: Haha, I tried that too. I even tried `Hide(); Show();`, and that didn't work either. I posted what finally worked. Thanks for the help!

Comment: That sounds like something that should be handled inside the Window class itself. What if the window was already shown (creating child outside)? `StateChanged` will be useless. I see they are internally calling `value.IsSourceWindowNull` but of cause they can't provide public property to check if it was shown...

Answer (score 10):

I ended up subscribing to `Window.Activated`, not `Window.StateChanged`. Be sure to unsubscribe to it in the handler, as advised in the comments.

```
    private void OnActivated(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        owned.Owner = this;
        Activated -= OnActivated;
    }
```

I accepted dlev's answer because it led me directly to finding the answer, even if his didn't work for my exact situation.

Answer (score 7):

Just adding another option if you need the handle created earlier than normal for some reason, or can't show the window:

`new WindowInteropHelper(myWindow).EnsureHandle();`

Answer (score 6):

You need the WPF equivalent of `HandleCreated` event, which is `SourceInitialized`. This should work:

```
public OwnerWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    SourceInitialized += (s, a) =>
        {
            var owned = new OwnedWindow();
            owned.Owner = this;
        };
}
```

Note that you don't have to `Show` either OwnerWindow or OwnedWindow for this to work.