# WPF window owner property issue

Tags: wpf, exception, owner

I have a `WPF MainWindow` where I can open a second one as follow, taking as an example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855954/showdialog-behind-the-parent-window):

```
var win = new CalibrationWindow(){Owner = this};
win.ShowDialog();
```

Rarely happens that I have the following runtime exception "`cannot set owner property to a window that has not been shown previously`".

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That probably indicates that `this` - your main window - has not been shown yet.

Comment: No, the Main Window is shown because I open the second window only after having pressed a button.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the StateChanged or Activated event of the window and set the Owner property in this event handler as suggested here:

[Having Trouble Setting Window's Owner in Parent's Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16550621/having-trouble-setting-windows-owner-in-parents-constructor)

```
var win = CalibrationWindow();
this.Activated += (s, e) => { win.Owner = this; };
win.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: What if I can open several Windows? If I do the following 

private void MainWindow_OnActivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ((Window) sender).Owner = this;
        }  I have an eception when I open the window at the first time.

Comment: The parent window *must* have been opened before you can use it as an owner of the child window.

Comment: Sure, the MainWindow is shown otherwise I can't press the button in order to show the second window.